# Git: How can I put a commit between older commits without changing the files/folders of later commits?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I have a repository with a series of commits. Lets say two old commits are A and directly after it C:

```
A--C
```

In commit C I have **not** checked in a *new version* of the old files, but in fact *completely new files* with the same name.

This makes the diff for commit C look messy - in fact this diff does not make sense as the files are completely different anyway.

What I want is to add a commit between A and C (let's call this one B then):

```
A--B--C
```

In this commit B I want to remove the files and folders, which I have changed with C.

I know that with the following I can add a new commit between A and C:

```
git rebase --interactive A^
```

then doing an "edit" on commit A

and then

```
git rm -rf file folder/
git commit -m "B" # New commit with name B
```

How do I now get the same files and folders, which I had after the original commit C, meaning *before* B was in place?

With other words: How can I get C again, but **without** the removal I did in B?

Comment: How about, update to A, commit B, rebase C on top of B? Or how about just committing B on top of A, merging with C, then comitting a new changeset on top of the merge to remove the unwanted parts? Do you *really* need to change the history?

Comment: After I had committed B on top of A, I have tried `git rebase --onto HEAD A master`. This will rebase C on top of B, however, this (logically) gives a series of merge conflicts. This is the situation I wanted to avoid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps I have done to solve the issue:

```
git checkout A
git rm -rf file folder/
# Create a new commit with name B on top of A:
git commit -m "B"
# On top of B create a new commit with what was C:
echo 'new C commit' | git commit-tree C^{tree} -p HEAD
```

This will create a new C commit and return its SHA hash. At this point, a checkout of the *new* C commit contains exactly what you would get, if you checked out the *original* C commit.

```
git checkout new-C-commit # No, this did not happen with git commit-tree
git rebase --onto HEAD C master
```

This rebases the branch (in my case it's master), starting with the first commit **after** the original C commit on the new C commit. This will apply without problems as both commits effectively create the same files and folders.

Comment: Thanks to knittl for setting me on the right track! Kudos go to him!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`git-commit-tree`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) for that:

```
git checkout A
git rm -rf file folder/
git commit -m 'B'
echo 'new C commit' | git commit-tree C -p HEAD
# create a new branch/update branch with the commit id printed by commit-tree
```

This will:

- Checkout A (detach HEAD)
- Remove files and folder, create a new commit `B`
- Create a new commit with the same set of files/state as the original commit C
- You will then have to update your old branch to point to the new commit (currently still a detached HEAD)

---

An alternative way might be to use grafts and then filter-branch to make them permanent:

```
git checkout A
git rm -rf file folder/
git commit -m B
echo `git rev-parse C` `git rev-parse HEAD` >> .git/info/grafts
git filter-branch A^..C
```

Comment: I have tried the first way you proposed. However, `git commit-tree C -p HEAD` does not work. It gives: *fatal: C is not a valid 'tree' object* (In fact I have replaced the "C" in your command with the commit-SHA of the according commit and this SHA is also what is mentioned in the error output).

Comment: @Christopher: try `C^{tree}` (replace C with your commit's hash/branch name)

Comment: This looks like it brings me to the solution. I'll double check and then once post the steps I had to do...